# How to stop adding a popup window each time clicking on the Hyperlinks from a Gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

A Column in a Gridview holds hyperlinks, clicking on the hyperlinks open the same popup  "popup.aspx" but holding dynamic data. How to open Just a single up window(certain height and width)?" Replacing first window by second window". Popup window keeps adding each time I click on the hyperlink.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"page_index_script2", "openNewWindow();", true);

Comment: Opening a new browser window on click is not a very good practice. Generally such things have been replaced by using a modal or dialog widget from a CSS framework, such as Bootstrap or jQuery UI. You get much tighter control using the modal.

Comment: If you really want to go down this route and use an actual popup and not a modal (which would be better) you might want to look into naming your window... with a name you can then target it with your hyperlinks. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp